# Python Class variable increments higher than the # of iterations

Tags: python

I'm a bit stumped on this one, and I'm sure it has to due with my lack of experience in Python OOP and how classes work, or how the new string formatting is functioning. Posting here so that others can reference if they have a similar issue.

The problem: I use the following Class as a generator in a loop to read in a file and parse it line by line. Each line of interest increments the `self.reads_total` variable by one, and if that line meets certain criteria, it increments the `self.reads_mapping` variable by 1. At the end (just before the `StopIteration()` call on the `next()` method, I output those two values to stdout. When I run this from the command line on a file with 52266374 lines, I get the following back:

`Reads processed: 5220000029016 with both mates mapped out of 52263262 total reads`

This output is generated just before the termination of the iteration by the following line of code:

`print("{0} with both mates mapped out of {1} total reads\n".format(self.reads_mapping, self.reads_total))`

The `self.reads_total` is outputting the correct # of iterations, but the `self.reads_mapping` is not.

Class object that is called by a simple `for x in SamParser(infile)` loop:

```
class SamParser:
"""This object takes as input a SAM file path and constructs an iterable that outputs
 sequence information.  Only one line will be held in memory at a time using this method.
"""
def __init__(self, filepath):
    """
    constructor
    @param filepath: filepath to the input raw SAM file.
    """
    if os.path.exists(filepath):  # if file is a file, read from the file
        self.sam_file = str(filepath)
        self.stdin = False
    elif not sys.stdin.isatty():  # else read from standard in
        self.stdin = True
    else:
        raise ValueError("Parameter filepath must be a SAM file")
    self.current_line = None
    self.reads_mapping = 0
    self.reads_total = 0
    # Allowable bitflags for SAM file -> reads with both mates mapping, regardless of other flags
    self.true_flags = (99, 147, 83, 163, 67, 131, 115, 179, 81, 161, 97, 145, 65, 129, 113, 177)

def __iter__(self):
    return self

def _iterate(self):
    # Skip all leading whitespace
    while True:
        if self.stdin:
            sam_line = sys.stdin.readline()  # read from stdin
        else:
            sam_line = self.sam_file.readline()  # read from file
        if not sam_line:
            return  # End of file
        if sam_line.startswith("@SQ"):  # these lines contain refseq length information
            temp = sam_line.split()
            return temp[1][3:], temp[2][3:]
        elif sam_line[0] != "@":  # these lines are the actual reads
            self.reads_total += 1
            if self.reads_total % 100000 == 0:  # update the counter on stdout every 100000 reads
                sys.stdout.write("\rReads processed: {}".format(self.reads_total))
                sys.stdout.flush()
            temp = sam_line.split()
            if int(temp[1]) in self.true_flags and temp[2] is not "*" and int(temp[3]) is not 0:
                self.reads_mapping += 1
                return temp[1], temp[2], temp[3], temp[9]
    self.sam_file.close()  # catch all in case this line is reached
    assert False, "Should not reach this line"

def next(self):
    if not self.stdin and type(self.sam_file) is str:  # only open file here if sam_file is a str and not file
        self.sam_file = open(self.sam_file, "r")
    value = self._iterate()
    if not value:  # close file on EOF
        if not self.stdin:
            self.sam_file.close()
        print("{0} with both mates mapped out of {1} total reads\n".format(self.reads_mapping, self.reads_total))
        raise StopIteration()
    else:
        return value
```

The full script can be found here if you need more context: https://github.com/lakinsm/file-parsing/blob/master/amr_skewness.py

Comment: I suggest you try to produce a replicable example using a smaller file.

Comment: `194 with both mates mapped out of 206 total reads`
The script performs correctly on a small test file of 206 lines, which means it's probably some logical/file format caveat I'm overlooking.  Thanks.  I'll report back when I find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple string formatting mistake: the script is designed to update the line count in place on stdout, and I didn't include a newline at the beginning of the next line, so it was overwriting the last line output, which included the large read count from the previous total. The true output should be:

```
Reads processed: 52200000
29016 with both mates mapped out of 52263262 total reads 
Plots generated: 310
```

In any case, the script is useful for SAM parsing if anyone stumbles upon this in the future.  Don't make my same mistake.